# ObjectStore put syntax

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm having trouble with the new syntax (r18915) for idb.ObjectStore.put. Could someone please help?
example is below which results in error as follows :

```dart
AsyncError: ‘Error:DataError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 0’
Stack trace: #0 ObjectStore._put_2(file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-trunk/build/src/build/Release/obj/
global_intermediate/webkit/bindings/dart/indexed_db/ObjectStore.dart:141:3) #1
  ObjectStore.$dom_put(file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-trunc/build/src/build/Release/obj/
global_intermediate/webkit/bindings/dart/indexed_db/ObjectStore.dart:137:18) #2
  ObjectStore.put(file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-trunc/build/src/build/Release/obj/
global_intermediate/webkit/bindings/dart/indexed_db/ObjectStore.dart:9:27)
```

The code I'm using which was working but has been modified for new release as follows :

```dart
Future fDbAddOrUpdateClient(String sKey1, ClassClientData clClientData) { 
  idb.Transaction oDbTxn         = ogDb1.transaction(sgStoreClient, 'readwrite');
  idb.ObjectStore oDbStoreClient = oDbTxn.objectStore(sgStoreClient);

  Completer completer = new Completer();
  var oDbReqPut = oDbStoreClient.put(
        {'sKey': sKey1,
         'sNameTitle'  : clClientData.sNameTitle, 
         'sNameFamily' : clClientData.sNameFamily,
         'sNameGiven1' : clClientData.sNameGiven1,
         'sNameGiven2' : clClientData.sNameGiven2
         })
         .then((val){
           completer.complete(val);
           return;
         })
         .catchError((e){
           window.alert("${e}");
           return;
         });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return a `completer.future` somewhere? BTW, Future can be given a specific type like `Future<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the future you specify your function returns but never does, only a completed value (as mentioned in other comment), the future syntax appears correct. The error itself actually indicates that the data being passed to your objectstore.put command is invalid.

See [IndexedDB Exceptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#exceptions). You may need to verify the data that is being passed to the map.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The main problem appeared to be with Database not opening or something related such as ObjectStore not being created, but no error shown.

Hopefully the following is better code (r19425) :

```
  Future future = fDbAddOrUpdateClient(sKey, clClientData)
   .catchError((oError) => window.alert("${oError}"));
}

Future fDbAddOrUpdateClient(String sKey1, ClassClientData clClientData) { 
  idb.Transaction oDbTxn         = ogDb1.transaction(sgStoreClient, 'readwrite');
  idb.ObjectStore oDbStoreClient = oDbTxn.objectStore(sgStoreClient);

  return oDbStoreClient.put(fMapClient(sKey1, clClientData));
}
```